# Name for phenomenon which causes bias in estimation of extreme percentiles of a distribution fitted to points with large error bars

Tags: bias, quantiles, lognormal-distribution

I have a series of small numbers (say 25-45) of values which were generated, and each value has an uncertainty associated with it. I also have a theory that says these points are supposed to fit well to a specific type of distribution (either log-normal or logistic), and I am interested in the 5th percentile of this distribution. I've noticed that often the error (95% CI) in the individual values is often up to half the spread of the distribution (from P5 to P95). In this case I believe I am generating a biased value by taking the 5th percentile of a distribution fitted to the individual points.

Does this phenomenon have a name? and is there a way to determine this bias?

User @whuber asked for more details. Basically I fit the distribution one of two ways:

1. I fit the predicted points ignoring the error.
2. I take into account the error and assume error in each individual point is independent and normally distributed, then randomly select a point within that normal distribution of error and I fit my distribution to these points. When the error in the individual points is large compared to the spread of the whole distribution, the values of the P5 are lower for the points that have the random noise added, but as the error in the points shrinks relative to the whole distribution this difference disappears.

Edit#2: More additional information, I use a software called "Oracle Crystal Ball" to fit the points to a distribution, I select the distribution type based on largely on the Anderson-Darling criteria, typically this criteria chooses the log-normal distribution, for the data I am generating. I hope this is what you wanted.

I am looking for a name or some resources on how to deal with this phenomenon.

Comment: Whether there is bias or not depends on *how* you are fitting the distribution. Could you edit this post to include a description of that?

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. It doesn't address my question, though: *how* do you "fit the predicted points"? Whether a procedure is biased or not depends on the details of the procedure, so if you don't tell us about that, it will be difficult to address your question.

Comment: Thank you for the edits (+1). I think I get the picture. What it seems to come down to is that your procedure is conflating measurement error in the points with the variation due to their underlying distribution.  (The admixture of Normal measurement error in a lognormal model is particularly a problem.  What would happen, for instance, if some of the random point selections happened to be *negative*?) This makes you concerned that the procedure might not be doing a good job at estimating a low percentile (which is a legitimate concern) and so you are wondering whether better procedures exist.